# how to wrap text around an image in flash (actionscript 3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hi I'm trying to set up a textfield which will wrap around an image using flash as3. Anyone have any pointers on how to accomplish that?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution outside of inserting an image in a text field with htmlText?

Comment: I would imagine every letter would have to be its own text area. anyway here is something you might want to invest in and study. http://activeden.net/item/floating-words-as3/126725

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats what you are looking for: http://partlyhuman.com/lab/textwrapping/

Get it here: http://dispatchevent.org/roger/dynamic-text-wrapping-in-actionscript-3/